# What is the ᴄᴏʀʀᴇᴄᴛ English pronunciation of a character pointer in C-like programming languages?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation, programming, cultural-correctness

In programming languages like C, Go, and C++, the [character pointer data
type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c)
is denoted using:

```
char *
```

What is the correct English pronunciation for this data type?

1. Is it /kɑr stɑr/, so with the ‹ch› of `char` pronounced as in *character* /ˈkerəktər/ and *choir* /kwɑɪr/?
2. Is it /tʃɑr stɑr/, so with the ‹ch› of `char` pronounced as in *chair* /tʃer/ and *child* /tʃɑɪld/?

My colleague has been arguing that the correct way is the second version, not the first version.

Who’s right?

Comment: An additional difficulty is the vowel—if you pronounce the _ch_ as [k] (like in ‘character’), do you then also pronounce the a as [æ] (as in ‘character’)? Or do you make the word homophonous with ‘car’? ’Cause /kær/ is not usually a permitted structure for a word to have in English. (I usually ignore this and /kær/, similar to how I pronounce _charset_ as /'kær.set/.)

Comment: I have never heard `char *` pronounced as "char star", only "char pointer".

Comment: There's this gem in [comp.lang.c infrequently asked questions](http://www.seebs.net/faqs/c-iaq.html): Q: How do you pronounce "char"? A: Like the first word of "char *". The accent is generally on the first syllable.

Comment: And do you pronounce ++ and either "pre- or post-increment"?

Comment: @Jim `++` is just "plus plus", just like `*` is "times" where appropriate. Oh, and I just realised that `/*` for comment is "slash star". Sorry for not being more consistent.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in in a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081753/how-to-pronounce-char-as-in-const-char), *[char](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/char?q=char)* is already a word in the English language; you should pronounce it the same way:

> **char** /CHär/

In my 20+ years as a C++ developer, I'd say 95% of the developers I've worked with have pronounced `char *` so the two parts rhyme:

> **char*** /CHär stär/

(Pronounced ***char***-star, which makes me think of a hamburger chef.)

However, software development is such an international community that I'd say that the most important rule is this: *Say it in a way that you are understood.*

Answer (score 1):

Such things don't always have a *correct* answer. In the English language, what works for most people is usually the *correct* answer - in other words, it's a *democratic* language.

In this case, saying *kar* would imply to the listener that you are aware that it's a short form of *character*. However, is *char* stands in itself, I've heard folk say *ch.ar* as in chair.

Comment: Most people I know pronounce it /tʃa:r/ rhymes with star with a 'ch' like church.  That gives "char star" a nice ring.  I admit that back in the late 70's I pronounced it /kær/ as short for character, but I quickly came to realize that this was not the accepted way.

Comment: As time goes on, shortened forms become full words in their own right, so I can see how what started off as /kær/ become the more natural /tʃa:r/. I'd say your own experience embodies the natural evolution of such words in English.

Answer (score 0):

It is pronounced as character. When you use %c in C language it is a symbol for character.so i believe it is pronounced as character. But in C/C++ books they are pronounce in both way,no differences. However because of the symbol its better to say it as you say character.

Answer (score 0):

It is pronounced **"char pointer"** (hard ch) or **"pointer to character"**

Similarly, char & is "char/character reference" or "reference to character"